# jQuery expression to pull attributes from tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

What jquery expression would give me `['a','b']` for the doc `<tag att1='a' /><tag att1='b' />`.

The actual case I'm working on is to list an array of all the images used in an html doc (not the  tags, but the actual locations of the images). So the desired result will be something like `["http://mywebsite.com/path_to_image_1.jpg", ...]` for a document that contains snippets like:

```
<img src="http://mywebsite.com/path_to_image_1.jpg" />
<img src="http://mywebsite.com/path_to_image_2.jpg" />
```

I really don't want to have to list all the `<img>` tags, then iterate manually to get the `src` attribute.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/140505)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var imgs = $('img').map(function(){
    return this.src;
}).get();
```

Comment: Marked as answer even though it doesn't completely achieve getting the array through using jQuery only.

Comment: @Trindaz: "through using jQuery only".  What do you mean by this?  `this.src` is actually *faster* than `$(this).attr('src')`.

Answer (score 3):

```
var array = $('img').map(function() { return this.src; }).toArray();
```

If it helps, here's a plugin that can automate the task if you need to do this for different elements and attributes.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.attrAsArray = function(attr) {
        return this.map(function() { return $(this).attr(attr); }).toArray();
    };
})(jQuery);



var array = $('img').attrAsArray('src');
```

Comment: You'll want to add `.get()` on the end to return an array.

Comment: Thanks James, you're right. I used toArray instead since it seems a little clearer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var imageArray = [];
$('img').each(function() {
    imageArray.push($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks adeneo, but I'm looking for a jQuery expression to handle it all for me without having to iterate over each img element.

Comment: Any such expression would iterate internally anyway, but whatever floats your boat!

Comment: It's not the iterating per se that I'm worried about. This is for use in a DSL where I want to avoid straight js as much as possible in favor of jQuery.

Comment: Don't hear that much, most of us would rather avoid jQuery if we could?

Comment: For a hacker yes, for a designer who'll be using the DSL no :)

Comment: @Trindaz: jQuery *is* JavaScript, and sometimes vanilla JS is *faster* than using jQuery.

Comment: @Rocket - plain JS is only faster for hackers, for designers jQuery is faster and better, obviously ! Doesn't matter if it just calls the same JS function in a rather large library of ...wait for it... plain JS functions or not.

Comment: @Rocket - pretty sure it was ;-) ______